# Angular filter use

Tags: angularjs, filter

Could someone give some clarificcation on the following code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {

$scope.handle = '';

$scope.lowercasehandle = function() {
    return $filter('lowercase')($scope.handle);
};

}]);
```

This code makes everything in the handle  into a lowercase.  My question is, where does the $filter('lowercase') come from?  How does the string "lowercase" know to make the handle all lowercase?  I did not define this anywhere in Angular.  Is 'lowercase' already built into angular somehow?

Comment: Yes, this filter comes with Angular (as do others, such as `currency` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter)

Comment: Read the fine manual ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/lowercase

Comment: ah! yes. sorry. was searching for the docu, but thanks for pointing that to me